# Documentation in Eclipse shows up as HTML

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, aptana, phpdoc

[image]

When I hover over a function, I get the documentation, but the HTML isn't being parsed. This happens to me in both Aptana 3 and Eclipse Helios. Any ideas? I'm clueless. Ubuntu 11.04 btw

EDIT:
When I press F2 for focus, the dialog turns yellow and the content is

```
<div class="header"PHP API
require_once
The require_once keyword
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you have Internal Web Browser available in your Eclipse. For this use menu Window/Show View/Other/Internal Web Browser.
If browser is not available, read [SWT FAQ: What do I need to run the SWT Browser inside Eclipse on Linux?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux)

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path. In the end, all I had to do was 'sudo apt-get install  XULrunner-1.9.2' Thanks!